# C# windows application binding a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datagridview, system.data.datatable

In my application I have 2 datatables. One is NameTable (Id,Name), other is FriendsTable(NameId,Name). NameId of FriendsTable is the Id of NameTable. Now in my application I want to display data in gridview as follows: Gridview should show NameTable rows
i.e. Id and Name and also displays count of Friends. So gridview must contain 3 columns, 2 displaying NameTable columns and third the count. 
When I double click a row of datagridview, the application must open other window which displays all the Friends in a table. 
I am stucked in first part of displaying the count column. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide what you've written so far?

Comment: I have just coded to feed data into datatable. I know how to bind a gridview with datatable. But adding one more column of count for records I am not getting. So, no coding of binding functionality till now.

Comment: Can you also provide skype account or anything so that I can chat directly ? Please provide skype ids or gtalk id so that we can chat and talk.